# Firefox 74 tabs on bottom - Overlapping panel issue

Tags: css, firefox

I have just updated to FF74 and my tabs-on-bottom configuration stopped working normally. The new version of the browser somehow produces an effect, where the tabs panel not only overlaps the upper (URL) toolbar, but also becomes invisible, except for the active tab. I'm attaching images illustrating the issue as well as the relevant tabs-on-top arrangement. I would greatly appreciate suggestions on how to fix this. (I assume that I need to add some CSS code to push the tabs panel below the URL one.)

[image: Issue with tabs on bottom]
[image: Normal behavior with tabs on top]

Contents of my "userChrome.css" file:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */


/* TABS: on bottom */

#navigator-toolbox toolbar:not(#nav-bar):not(#toolbar-menubar) {-moz-box-ordinal-group:10}

#TabsToolbar {-moz-box-ordinal-group:1000!important}


#TabsToolbar {

display: block !important;

position: absolute !important;

bottom: 0 !important;

width: 100vw !important;

}


#tabbrowser-tabs {

width: 100vw !important;

}

#main-window:not([chromehidden*="toolbar"]) #navigator-toolbox {padding-bottom: var(--tab-min-height) !important;}


/* TABS: height */

:root {

--tab-toolbar-navbar-overlap: 0px !important;

--tab-min-height: 36px !important; /* adjust to suit your needs */

}

:root #tabbrowser-tabs {

--tab-min-height: 36px !important; /* needs to be the same as above under :root */

--tab-min-width: 80px !important;

}


#TabsToolbar {

height: var(--tab-min-height) !important;

margin-bottom: 1px !important;

box-shadow: ThreeDShadow 0 -1px inset, -moz-dialog 0 1px !important;

background-color: var(--toolbar-bgcolor) !important;

}


#tabbrowser-tabs,

#tabbrowser-tabs > .tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox,

.tabbrowser-tabs[positionpinnedtabs] > .tabbrowser-tab[pinned] {

min-height: var(--tab-min-height) !important;

max-height: var(--tab-min-height) !important;

}


/* drag space */

.titlebar-spacer[type="pre-tabs"],

.titlebar-spacer[type="post-tabs"] {

width: 40px;

}


/* Override vertical shifts when moving a tab */

#navigator-toolbox[movingtab] > #titlebar > #TabsToolbar {

padding-bottom: unset !important;

}

#navigator-toolbox[movingtab] #tabbrowser-tabs {

padding-bottom: unset !important;

margin-bottom: unset !important;

}

#navigator-toolbox[movingtab] > #nav-bar {

margin-top: unset !important;

}


/* hide windows-controls */

#TabsToolbar #window-controls {display:none!important;}


/* move caption buttons to right of Tab bar */

#main-window[tabsintitlebar]:not([inFullscreen="true"]) #toolbar-menubar[autohide="true"] ~ #TabsToolbar .titlebar-buttonbox-container {

position: fixed !important;

right: 0 !important;

top: calc(6px + var(--tab-min-height)) !important;

display: block !important;

visibility: visible !important;

}

#toolbar-menubar[autohide="true"] ~ #TabsToolbar {padding-right: 100px !important;}
```